# Thin arrow inside circle using css (for use with React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I found some interesting arrow inside circle, here it is -

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SachaJolly/pen/oWQMoG)
```

I took this example from the website - https://freebiesupply.com/blog/css-arrows/
part *Arrowed Link – Circle On Hover (cf Google Home Website)*

I am not very experienced in css, so I couldn't correctly make the same arrow in my application. I tried different converters to usual css, but was't successful. Only I need is simply define this styles (or maybe there is another approach) and use it in JSX code.

Maybe do you have any ideas how to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you heard about Material UI? You have to install the library and the import the icon. `import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown'; `. Probably you would need to close this question. Enter here and read the documentation https://mui.com/es/components/material-icons/

Comment: Sure, but I have my own style, and just want to add only one arrow, but if it is the only way, maybe I will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use SVGs or icon font like [material icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) or [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/).
They are best to work with, easy to manipulate.

If you really want to do it in css you can do something like this:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.arrowDown {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
.arrowDown span:first-child,
.arrowDown span:last-child {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 5.2px;
}
.arrowDown span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
  left: 5.2px;
}
.arrowDown span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="arrowDown">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</span>
```

Comment: you will have to change many things in order to change the height and width, just like the placement of the arrow; thats why font is good.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted the HTML source code into this website's converter, https://pughtml.com to get the following:

```
<section className="centered-container"><a className="link link--arrowed" href="#">Ceci est un magnifique bouton<svg className="arrow-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <g fill="none" stroke="#2175FF" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10">
    <circle className="arrow-icon--circle" cx="16" cy="16" r="15.12"></circle>
    <path className="arrow-icon--arrow" d="M16.14 9.93L22.21 16l-6.07 6.07M8.23 16h13.98"></path>
  </g>
</svg></a></section>
```

I also copied and pasted the scss into this website's converter, https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css to get the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.centered-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 4rem;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
}
.link {
    color: #2175ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.link--arrowed {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
}
.link--arrowed .arrow-icon {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.link--arrowed .arrow-icon--circle {
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease;
    stroke-dasharray: 95;
    stroke-dashoffset: 95;
}
.link--arrowed:hover .arrow-icon {
    transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
}
.link--arrowed:hover .arrow-icon--circle {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

It worked for me.